# setup a different web-server for an already existing url

Tags: html, webserver

This may be naive question. I'm trying to build my own webpage and I already have a url under a domain name that I like to keep. Its basically a school provided address that looks like `http://www.uni.edu/~mypage`.

Problem is I am interested to run custom server-side apps but do not have the authority to run them on the machine that hosts the page. However I have access to other local machines that are always on the network and access the webpage directory via ssh. Is it possible to move my files into this machine and run the webserver there but somehow still have the same existing url?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take control of only a URL *path*. The domain `www.uni.edu` will still have to point to the same server it's pointing to now, and the web server running there will have to handle the path `~mypage` as it is now. The only thing you can do is set up a proxy which specifically forwards requests to this path internally to another server. In Apache this can be easily done in an .htaccess file with mod_rewrite and the `[P]` flag, for example (and/or other configuration options with mod_proxy). However, the admin of the current web server will have to allow and/or configure this for you.